# Compare instances or objects of same UIViewController class

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have created two instances of a MasterViewController derived from UIViewController class

```
_masterViewController = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MasterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

// second instance with same class and duplicate nib view
_favItemMasterVC = [[MasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"favMasterViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
```

Both the MasterViewController_iPhone & favMasterViewController_iPhone view are same.
Now I want to check which of the UIViewController is currently selected(eg:on tabbar). 
How can i find the difference between both objects?

`- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{`

`if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[_favItemListMasterVC class]] 
    { // it is always called in both cases}`

isMemberOfClass: // is also not working

How to check the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I have understand what are you doing, but if _favItemListMasterVC and _masterViewController are pointing to the same VCs added to the UITabBar, you can check it simply comparing pointers

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

if (viewController == _favItemListMasterVC)
{
    //the visible view controller is _favItemListMasterVC
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
   - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
if (viewController == _masterViewController)
{

}
else if (viewController == _favItemMasterVC)
{

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use tag to check which is which. Tag is property of a [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView) Set the tag value in the two xib files. And check the tag using code.

Answer (score 1):

To compare objects you can also use:

```
if([viewController isEqual:_favItemMasterVC])
```